# Error stating: column "apple" already belongs to this data table

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datatable

The code below is an example of my original which is receiving the listed error in the title of this post.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Clear()
        dt.Columns.Add("apple")
        dt.Columns.Add("apple 1")
    Dim mr As DataRow
        mr = dt.NewRow
        mr("apple") = "Macbook"
        mr("apple 1") = "ipod"
    dt.Rows.Add(mr)
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this code section is in a loop then consider the followings:

- `dt.Clear()` removes all rows from the `DataTable` but NOT the columns
- `dt.Columns.Clear()` will remove all the columns.

Anyway you don't need to always clear and add the same columns to the data table. Do it once outside the loop.

Comment: marked this as the answer. Please upvote for future guests thanks